# R2DBC Postgres connection fails

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

My connection config:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableR2dbcRepositories
public class DatabaseConfiguration extends AbstractR2dbcConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public PostgresqlConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return new PostgresqlConnectionFactory(PostgresqlConnectionConfiguration.builder()
            .host("r2dbc:postgresql://mydb.alfa")
            .port(5432)
            .username("admin")
            .database("postgres")
            .password(password)
            .build()
        );
    }
}
```

My repository:

```java
public interface ReactiveOdometerRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<OdometerEntity, String> {
    Flux<OdometerEntity> findTop1By(String name);
}
```

My entity:

```java
@Setter
public class OdometerEntity {
    @Getter
    @Id
    private String name;
    @Getter
    private int value;
}
```

When I try querying the DB, it fails:

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/query", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public int get(@RequestBody RequestObject request) {
    return odometerRepository.findTop1ByName(request.getName()).getValue();
```

Error:

```
io.r2dbc.postgresql.PostgresqlConnectionFactory$PostgresConnectionException: 
Cannot connect to r2dbc:postgresql://mydb.alfa/<unresolved>:5432
```

Not sure what the `unresolved` is doing in there.

How do I fix this error? thanks

Comment: I would expect the `host` property to contain the name of the host, **not** the full URL. So I would expect `host("mydb.alfa")`.

Comment: thanks, this fixed the problem. please feel free to add this as an answer and i'll accept it. or i can create the answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `host` variable is wrong. It should contain **only** the name or ip-address of the host not the full URL.

So instead of `host("r2dbc:postgresql://mydb.alfa")` use `host("mydb.alfa")`.

```java
@Bean
public PostgresqlConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    return new PostgresqlConnectionFactory(PostgresqlConnectionConfiguration.builder()
        .host("mydb.alfa")
        .port(5432)
        .username("admin")
        .database("postgres")
        .password(password)
        .build()
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify host name in the host, not the url there

```java
 PostgresqlConnectionFactory(
     PostgresqlConnectionConfiguration.builder()
         .host("localhost")
         .database("blogdb")
         .username("user")
         .password("password")
         .codecRegistrar(
              EnumCodec
                 .builder()
                 .withEnum("post_status", Post.Status.class)
                 .build()
         )
         .build()
)
```

There are [a few r2dbc connectionfactory examples](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample/tree/master/connection-factories/src/main/java/com/example/demo) from my Github.

Comment: thanks for sharing the samples. I wish I had these when i was writing the code initially!